# How can I make text in a marquee element to scroll continuously?

Tags: html, css, marquee

I have a the next marquee element:

```
<marquee height="450px" class="quotes" behavior="scroll" direction="up" scrollamount="2">
  Sal ahí fuera y prueba diferentes cosas hasta que descubras donde dan resultado tus talentos,
  intereses y prioridades<br /><br />
  The best founders get things done every time. Small chunks at a time.<br /><br />
  Tienes que amar la idea en cuestión, tienes que sentir pasión por ella, si no, te pondrás contra las
  cuerdas todos los días.<br /><br />
  People can dismiss your start-up but you never can.<br /><br />
  You cant build Twitter looking for it. Make something unsexy people will pay for.<br /><br />
  Las ideas que parecen malas son las mejores, ya que no hay gente trabajando en ellas.<br /><br />
  Intensity→ you can't have other hobbies.<br /><br />
  Lo mejor es ir a por un mercado pequeño pero en crecimiento y expandirse desde ahí.
</marquee>
```

The text start from bottom and scroll to top, once the last text line appears, doesn't appear any other until this reach the top.

I want my text to start in the top and scroll up, also when the last quote appears, I don't want to wait until this to reach the top to see the first one, I want no space between them.

Is this possible?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The marquee element is obsolete at this point. Ideally you would find a different way to achieve the same result (Browsers may or may not support it, and it could be removed at any point) It shouldn't be too hard to come up with a bit of JS, or maybe even CSS animation to do this.

Comment: "*Browsers...may not support it, and it could be removed at any point.*" - one can only hope for such a day...